# Anything vs. something usage in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It's not like there's **anything** else to do.

Shouldn't the speaker say: "There's something else to do." ? so what's the meaning of the sentence and what's the difference between the two of them?
Thank you,

Comment: From a related ELU answer, [**Any** is a Negative Polarity Item, and thus requires a negative context...](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/174481/2637) As John Lawler points out there, *Did he eat **any** breakfast?* and *Did he eat **some** breakfast?* are both valid, and near-equivalent in meaning. Same thing with ***anything / something*** in your exact example, or *Is there **anything / something** I can do to help?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I've read somewhere, that "Did he eat some breakfast?" implies that there was some breakfast, while "Did he eat any breakfast?" does not.

Comment: some is used...
• in affirmative sentences (sentences which
are not negatives or questions)
• in questions where we expect agreement
or the answer 'Yes'
• Didn't John's parents give him some
money? (= I think/expect they did)
• Hasn't there been some discussion
about the proposal? (= I think/expect
there has)    _Advanced Grammar in Use - Martin Hewings 1st ed._

Comment: @Mv Log: I really think that distinction is clutching at straws. Both phrasings are equally credible regardless of whether the speaker knows anything at all about whether breakfast was "available" to him or not. And both can be forced to the sense of ***at least part of the breakfast he was presented with*** (if he's an invalid with no appetite, say), by placing stress on the chosen determiner (***some*** or ***any***).

Comment: ...but they're obviously not *always* interchangeable: You'll certainly never hear *Don't give me **some** lip, you cheeky boy!* - it's always ***any*** in negated contexts like that.

Answer (score 1):

"It's not like" or "it's not as if" precede a deliberately false statement, to emphasise its falseness, e.g. "It's not like we have a choice" (we don't have a choice). The sentence could be related to a statement or question:

Why are we staying at work? It's not like there's anything else to do.

We should leave. It's not like there's anything else to do.

> Often used for saying that something is not true and therefore it
>   cannot be the explanation for someone’s behaviour:
>
> I can’t understand why he disapproves of me. It’s not as if I’ve done
>   anything wrong.

[It's not as if](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-s-not-as-if)

Answer (score 0):

It's not like there is anything else to do is a negative sentence, meaning there is nothing else to do. Not anything = nothing
There is something else to do is a positive sentence, it means the opposite of the first sentence, there is something else to do. You have a choice, an alternative.

Comment: Some of what you say might be true in other contexts, but using ***something*** instead of ***anything*** in OP's specific context makes little if any difference to the meaning.